# What's the difference between ReadDirectoryChangesW() and FindFirstChangeNotification() APIs?

Tags: winapi, readdirectorychangesw

I want to know any change files of the specific directory. So, I figured out `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` and `FindFirstChangeNotification()` - `FindNextChangeNotification()` APIs.

Then, I implemented using `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` function. But, I don't know the why there are `FindFirst...` APIs.
I think that `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` function can do all of works of `FindFirst...` APIs.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Creates a change notification handle and sets up initial change notification filter conditions. {...} ***This function does not indicate the change that satisfied the wait condition***. To retrieve information about the specific change as part of the notification, use the ReadDirectoryChangesW function.

[ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves information that describes the changes within the specified
>   directory. The function does not report changes to the specified
>   directory itself.

### Conclusion:

If you want to register a file listener then use *FindFirstChangeNotification* but keep in mind that this function DOESN'T wait for a change, in order to achieve that you need to use *WaitForSingleObject* AFTER registering the file listener.

If you don't care about the type of the change in the path you are listening then there is **no need** to use *ReadDirectoryChangesW*. If you need to know what is the exact change that triggered *WaitForSingleObject* then you **need** to use *ReadDirectoryChangesW*.